Helm Conversion issues: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Secret.data of type map[string][]uint8
Output of helm version: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.14.4", GitCommit:"81c902a123462fd4052bc5e9aa9c513c4c8fc142", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.22.2"}
Output of openshift version: 4.13.38
Cloud Provider/Platform (AKS, GKE, Minikube etc.): Private Cloud, Openshift Cluster


Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Secret.data of type
map[string][]uint8
Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8
Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8
Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8


Hello everybody, we are trying to restructure some of our deployments into helm Charts and I am unable to fix the issue mentioned. Our initial take on the creation of this secret was oc create secret --from-file= and it worked without any issues, however in Helm it seems that the Go language has some problems with converting the data part of the secret into a map.
I've been trying to find a solution for days now. I also tried importing tpl functions, tried with include, Files.Get, but somehow I end up at the same result. Any idea on how to solve this would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
{{- range $relatedClusters := .Values.relatedClusters }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $relatedClusters.name }}
  namespace: {{ $.Values.project }}
data:
  {{ $relatedClusters.name }}:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Config
    clusters:
    - name: {{ (split "-" $relatedClusters.name)._0 }}
      cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: {{ $relatedClusters.certData | toString}}
        server: {{ $relatedClusters.server }}
    contexts:
    - name: istiod-basic@{{ (split "-" $relatedClusters.name)._0 }}
      context:
        cluster: {{ (split "-" $relatedClusters.name)._0 }}
        namespace: istio-system
        user: istiod-basic
    users:
    - name: istiod-basic
      user:
        token: {{ $relatedClusters.token | toString }}
  current-context: istiod-basic@{{ (split "-" $relatedClusters.name)._0 }}
  {{- end }}

The value entries that I am working with right now are:
relatedClusters:
  - name: access-cluster
    server: https://dummyurl1:1234
    certData: test
    token: test
  - name: ha-cluster
    server: https://dummyurl2:2345
    certData: test
    token: test
  - name: worker1-cluster
    server: https://dummyurl3:4567
    certData: test
    token: test

This issue DOES NOT show up when using --dry-run. When I use --dry-run the Secret resource is being created by helm without any issues.

A Secret is a simple string-keyed, string-valued map, where the values are usually base64 encoded. It can't hold structured data.  How are you trying to use this Secret value?
